# Arctext works differently on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arctext.js

I'm using [Arctext](https://github.com/codrops/Arctext) to curve some text on my web page.

However I have a problem.

When I link to the page the first time the curve is just seen slightly like below

[image]

When I reload the page however the curve comes properly as seen in this image

[image]

That's the HTML :

```
<div class='row'>
 <div class='columns '>
<hr class='songtitlehr'>
<p class='sotd'>SONG OF THE DAY</p>
    <p class='songtitle'>SOTD</p>
<p class='songartist '>BY CARL SALDANHA</p>

<p class='sotd2'>SONG OF THE DAY</p>

<hr class='songtitlehr'>
 </div> 
</div>
```

That's the JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.sotd').arctext({radius:240});
     $('.sotd2').arctext({radius:240, dir:-1});
    });
```

Comment: do you have jsfiddle or a link to the live page?

Comment: I can't seem to replicate it on JS fiddle. I suspect its something about the time my browser (chrome) is calculating the height for the arc. As JS fiddle reloads every time its like requesting the GET again. I'll get a live page up in like an hour and share it